# Currency symbol going to the wrong side of the value in Hebrew

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to combine two strings. One of them is a currency formatted using NSNumberFormatter and the other one is a simple text in Hebrew language.

Take a look at this example image:

[image: Screenshot]

When I display each of the texts in a separate label they appear correctly (first and second UILabels of the image), but the currency symbol switches side when I combine them (the third UILabel on the image). The piece code below is what I used to create this example:

```
// test value
double value = 1234567.89;

// formatting to use currency markers
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *number = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:value]];

// example text
NSString *text = @"ברוכים הבאים!";

// combining they together to display
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",text,number];
```

How could I combine them without this effect to happen? It works OK when using left-to-right languages. It only appears to happen on right-to-left languages.

Comment: I had a similar experience and just accepted it that this is the way to format currencies in RTL languages.

Comment: but is this really the right way? would it be correct in Hebrew?